# How can I fill a shape with a gradient on p5.js?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

First, I do know how to make gradients when it's formed within a square shape as its' a default shape when making manual gradients with `for` loops and `lerpColor`.

I am trying to create ideally any shape, in this case an ellipse that will have a linear gradient as a fill color. What I will do with this gradient is that I will have it animate across the page, so that it will create various shapes with the gradient.

I went to the p5.js example page to look for creating gradients, however I only managed to find gradients made manually using `line()`, `stroke()` and `lerpColor`. I looked around Processing forums and [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@behreajj/color-gradients-in-processing-v-2-0-e5c0b87cdfd2) though I don't have an understanding on Processing syntax.

Is there a way to tackle this?

Comment: The main (Java-based) version of processing maps to p5.js in a fairly mechanical way. If you just try to implement some of the functions in that Medium article, you might find it not as bad as you fear. Perhaps you can try to do so and then ask a more focused question. It is a somewhat surprising gap in the p5.js library that it doesn't deal with gradients as well as the HTML5 canvas does.

Answer (score 3):

Porting code from Processing to p5.js is very straightforward,- simply replace variable type (*int*,*float*,...) in declarations into Javascript generic type `var`, and everything will just work out-of-the-box. For example, [radial gradient](https://processing.org/examples/radialgradient.html) Processing code ported into P5.JS is :

```
var dim;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(640, 360);
  dim = width/2;
  background(0);
  colorMode(HSB, 360, 100, 100);
  noStroke();
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);
  frameRate(1);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  for (var x = 0; x <= width; x+=dim) {
    drawGradient(x, height/2);
  } 
}

function drawGradient(x, y) {
  var radius = dim/2;
  var h = random(0, 360);
  for (r = radius; r > 0; --r) {
    fill(h, 90, 90);
    ellipse(x, y, r, r);
    h = (h + 1) % 360;
  }
}
```

So, I will not dare to call it a "porting", it's a copy-paste operation by nature to 99.9% accuracy ! HTH !